# video streaming to smart tv (dlna/upnp)

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, streaming, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to stream to a smart tv via HTTP a video stream from ffmpeg. It works for about 5-10 mins then tv ends playback. I have investigated the issue with wireshark and found out that tv sends a Zero Window packet when it stops playback. I suspect that tv reaches a point where its I/O or CPU is overloaded.
I have attached the wireshark capture [FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyhzcckygdf884j/tv-capture.pcapng?dl=0)(trimmed down) and a screenshot.

192.168.0.103 => TV (Samsung UE42F5500) 
192.168.0.101 => PC  (tv and pc are both connected to router using cable no wifi)
[image: Wireshark PC-TV capture]

Streaming is done with a C# application which uses HTTPListener. I have tried many things for many days & nights, but changing the codec,bitrate,container and various ffmpeg options for error corection have no impact on the playback time. Recently i tried to add a small sleep while sending the stream to tv with great results, before this TV stopped in ~2-4 mins now with the 20ms sleep it stops in ~30 mins. So this leads me to think that the PC sends faster than the tv can handle. If i increase the sleep, playback becomes jerky and distorted if i reduce it TV stops sooner. This is the point i reached where i don't have any ideas on what to try, any hint or idea will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Below is the snippet which sends data to TV.

```
  void AcceptRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListenerContext ctx = null;
        try
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            ctx = listener.EndGetContext(result);
            listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(AcceptRequest), listener);
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            ctx.Response.Headers.Clear();
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "video/x-ms-asf");
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("transferMode.dlna.org", "Streaming");

            // tv first sends a HEAD to get the headers then a GET to get the actual content then it plays
            if (ctx.Request.HttpMethod != "HEAD")
            {
                using (Stream outputStream = ctx.Response.OutputStream)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //input stream comes from ffmpeg, i get it making a TcpClient connection in this method
                        using (Stream inputStream = GetVideoStream()) 
                        {
                            int bytesRead = 1;
                            while (bytesRead != 0)
                            {
                                //buffer size is 4096
                                byte[] buff = new byte[TransmitBufferSize + 1];
                                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buff, 0, TransmitBufferSize);

                                outputStream.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
                                outputStream.Flush();

                                //this is the silly workaround that "slows" down the stream and allows the tv to play longer
                                Thread.Sleep(20);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (HttpListenerException ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.ErrorCode != 62)//The specified network name is no longer available
                            Globals.Log("Error on VideoServer Buffer copy loop exception={0} callerInfo={1} ", ex.ToString(), PrintDebugCallerInfo(ctx));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                        Globals.Log("Error on VideoServer Buffer copy loop exception={0} callerInfo={1} ", ex2.ToString(), PrintDebugCallerInfo(ctx));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.Log("Error on Accept request, callerInfo={0} exception={1}",PrintDebugCallerInfo(ctx), ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.Response.Close();
            }

            catch (HttpListenerException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode != 1229)//connection invalid, normal it can occur
                    Globals.Log("Error closing response, error code:{0} ex:{1}",ex.ErrorCode, ex.ToString());
            }
            catch(Exception ex2)
            {
                Globals.Log("Error closing response, error ex:{0}",ex2.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

The data flow is : Sopcast Stream -> Decoded&Encoded with ffmpeg (to avoid any errors form sopcast) -> my c# code (make the stream upnp compatible) -> TV

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 years late but maybe someone will find this answer useful. All of these TV devices have limited memory in which they can decoded the frames. Its possible that you set the DPB (decoded picture buffer) too high. This buffer will be large if you set the number of reference frames to be large.

For example, if you use -refs 16 that means that for a frame that was compressed using 16 surrounding frames TV needs to decode all of those 16 frames in order to fully display that one. If your TV cant put all of those frames in memory you have a problem.

Best way to test if this is the case is to only use I frames for example.